# SQL rawquery in android

Tags: android

I know my question is very simple, I am trying to work out this rawQuery for hour, any help will be highly appreciated...

```
String queryString = "SELECT _id FROM " +  TABLE_SELECTED_ONE + " WHERE DifficultyLevel=? AND Attempt=?"; 
    Cursor cursor = Db.rawQuery(queryString, new String[] {beginnerOrAdvanced, "no"} );
```

but it crashes

```
12-08 02:18:33.091: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(546): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.wissenways.practicequestion/com.wissenways.practicequestion.QuesBankSelect}: android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: near ".": syntax error: , while compiling: SELECT _id FROMQuantQuesBank1WHEREQuantQuesBank1.DifficultyLevel='beginner' ANDQuantQuesBank1.Attempt ='no'
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I never got args to work in all the apps I published, try

```
Db.rawQuery(queryString, null);
```

and build up your string in it's full state as a pure string

example :

```
String dateString = Utils.makeDateString(mCalDate);
String sqlQuery = "select * from table where entrydate = '" + dateString + "'";

mSearchCursor = db.rawQuery(sqlQuery, null);
```

That way you can always run the SQL query in a SQL browser app on the table (extract from phone via DDMS) and check it works outside of Android.

It's just the output looks very wrong and spaces have been removed that were essential